Understanding Session State and Control Flow in Streamlit Chatbot App
Github Code link
Link above is a GitHub code of chatbot app using streamlit. Although it works fine, I have few questions regarding Streamlit.

What is the purpose of ‘if 'messages' not in st.session_state:’?
Why can’t I just use st.session_state['messages'] = [{'role': 'assistant', 'content':  ‘Hello?'}]
Because when I run the app for the first time, I think it is obvious there is no message. So what is the point of this?

I dont understand why this code has to be in if statement. As fas as I know, if statement runs once. But in streamlit app, it runs multiple times
and continues the conversations. I assume there should be ‘for loop’ inside or outside if statement but it works fine without it. Can you please explain why?


if prompt := st.chat_input():
    st.session_state['messages'].append({'role': 'user', 'content': prompt})
    st.chat_message('user').write(prompt)

    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model='gemma2-9b-it',
        messages=context + st.session_state['messages']
    )
    
    msg = response.choices[0].message.content
    st.session_state['messages'].append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': msg})
    st.chat_message('assistant').write(msg)

